# Formal definitions of the Universe

Tags: cosmology, resource-recommendations, definition, universe

I'm looking for formal, i.e. citable, definitions of the Universe. To my surprise, I couldn't find any in textbooks at my disposal. All I found were definitions in online dictionaries and Wikipedia article that cites Zeilik's definition from the Glossary at the very end of his book.

It all goes along the lines of "Universe is everything: universe is all of space and time and their contents."

Are you aware of any textbooks or peer reviewed articles, where the Universe is defined formally, and preferably discussed before plunging into mathematical descriptions of the observed phenomena?

Comment: In what way do you expect to "formalize" this ?

Comment: There is only one formal definition that I'm aware of and everything from the physical universe to universes in statistics that stem from the mathematical notion of a Universe. So what formality are you looking for here, exactly?